# Utilising output of WebMethod

Tags: .net, asp.net-ajax, webmethod

I'm calling a WebMethod using the ASP .NET AJAX Framework.  In the success method, I'm trying to use the return value of the WebMethod.  I keep on getting told it's undefined, even though when I'm debugging with Edge I can see that there is a value.

This is the code where I call the WebMethod:

```
Timebox.CreateNew(timeboxName, timeboxDate, startTime, endTime,  CreateTimeboxCallback, CreateTimeboxErrorCallback);
```

and here is the success callback function:

```
function CreateTimeboxCallback(response) {
  alert(response.d);
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following messagebox:

[image]

When I debug using the browser developer tools, or use console.log(response);, I get the following (which is exactly what the WebMethod is supposed to return):

[image]

I want to be able to use the values in ErrorCode and ErrorMessage.  Please can someone assist.

Comment: well, if you are getting an error message - is your error callback being called? Also, response is an array `[[object Object]]`, so try alerting `response[0].ErrorMessage`

Comment: Thank you, it's working!  Do you know why it doesn't require using response.d[0].ErrorMessage?

Comment: I've added answer below.  Please accept as answer. As far as why it doesn't require -> what is `d`? It isn't part of your response object so is undefined. Why are you trying to reference it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are getting an error message - is your error callback being called? Also, response is an array `[[object Object]]`, so try alerting `response[0].ErrorMessage`